# Post lacks formatting when being edited

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown, markdown-rendering

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975573/1469208) has perfectly formatted code in the beginning. However, when I hit the [`edit` link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3975573/edit) it turns out, that code is no longer formatted, because it starts without first four spaces.

What am I missing? How can a piece of Markdown be formatted and not formatted in the same time?

This seems to be a bug, as it affects multiple posts, especially very old ones which have not been edited since about 2010. This should be fixed.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. The HTML markup of posts is only generated from Markdown on creation and edition. The rest of the time (views), it is fetched verbatim from the database to keep the perfs up. It *could be* that the answer was edited "out of band" (maybe directly through the DB) without its markup being regenerated.

Comment: Well, when you submit or edit a post, it gets rendered into HTML on the server, and that HTML is stored and served with each subsequent request to view that post. The original Markdown version is also stored, for editing. Maybe the two versions in the SE database somehow got out of sync.

Comment: I wonder how many people have clicked on "edit" in that post in the last 10 minutes... :)

Comment: I wonder if this affects any other posts...

Comment: @JonasCz 1:9,545,600 chance that is unique. Not saying it's easy to *find* another.

Comment: @BillWoodger I believe SEDE has both the rendered HTML and the markdown version of posts, so it should not be too hard with some SQL.

Comment: Haha "perfectly formatted code" Are you having a laugh mate? I have to scroll horizontally for miles just to read it.

Comment: If the earlier comments are right that the rendered HTML is only generated when editing, then it's possible that the rendering process changed over the years. The post was last edited in 2010, so if the markdown parser at that time detected it as code, and the current markdown parser does not, that would explain it. But it's a total guess, and I have no idea how to verify this.

Comment: Pf, [DJDavid98](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1344955/djdavid98) just edited it, so that's no longer observable...

Comment: There are plenty of other examples that can indeed be found through simple SEDE queries. [Here's one.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1243/edit) To other lurkers, there is no benefit in editing the answer, so please don't bother.

Comment: @hvd Could you link to the query you used?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I didn't save it, but I just looked for old posts where the body (the HTML) starts with `<pre><code>`. There's plenty of them that don't use spaces on the first line.